# Rave Report: delete specific pages dynamically

Tags: delphi, pdf

I use Rave Report. I generate a PDF report that contains a few pages.

I need to skip (or delete) generation of some of the pages, if data related to those pages is not available.

Many thanks for your help,

Phil.